# How do I make setters and getters for JList and DefaultListModel? (Java)

Tags: java, swing, jlist, getter-setter, defaultlistmodel

I am writing a program that uses several custom `jpanels` to essentially make a Word-pad. This `jpanels`is supposed to allow the user to select a color from a Color-chooser and add or remove it from a `jlist`. In order for the window that will use the `jpanels`to be able to get the data from the `jpanels`, I was instructed to make setters and getters for my DefaultListModel and `jlist`. I have no idea how to do this with these types. I have seen examples of setters and getters for parameterized ArrayLists, and that seemed promising, but I still don't understand how to apply it to the listModel and `jlist`.

```
    private ArrayList<String> stringlist = new ArrayList<String>();

public ArrayList<String> getStringList() {
return stringlist;
}

public setStringList(ArrayList<String> list) {
stringlist = list
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check this. if we have a `JList` and a `DefaultListModel`

```
  JList listvariable= new JList();
  DefaultListModel model= new DefaultListModel<>();
```

Now these are the getter and setter methods for the same:

```
   public DefaultListModel getModel() {
   return model;
    }
    public void setModel(DefaultListModel model) {
    this.model = model;
    }



    public JList getListvariable() {
    return listvariable;
    }


    public void setListvariable(JList listvariable) {
    this.listvariable = listvariable;
    }
```

Comment: Ohhhh, okay. So, supposing that you declared the model and JList in a constructor and the getters and setters are outside of that constructor (but in the same class), how would you make the list and model accessible to the methods? Do you think I really need to have a constructor if the class is extending JPanel? @bhavna garg

Comment: You can see the getter methods take these components as arguments and setter methods  return this components. These methods thus automatically access these components.And you do not require these methods on a basic purpose. @Brooklyn

Comment: Okay, I understand that part. But getModel, for example, has to return an object (model) that was declared outside of that method. What if model had been declared inside of a constructor? How would the getModel method be able to access it?

Comment: You need to declare it globally not inside constructors. @Brooklyn

Answer (score 1):

In order to get the selected value from a JList, one should follow these steps:

- Create a class that extends JFrame and implements ActionListener interface.
- Create an array of objects. These will be the values of the JList.
- Create a new JList with the above array.
- Create a new JButton. Add an ActionListener to the button and override the actionPerformed method. Now every time the user presses the button this method will fire up.
- Call getSelectedIndex to get the index of the selected item in the JList.
- Call getSelectedValue method to get the value of the selected item in the JList.

Comment: I have to make the ActionListener in a separate class. This class is only supposed to have the panel with the JList and DefaultListModel. So the getters and setters I need recall the entire JList and DefaultListModel (not just the selected index).